# How to run a piece of code before continue/break/return statement in Kotlin elvis operator?

Tags: kotlin, elvis-operator

Imagine a function like this:

```kotlin
fun foo(bar: Bar) {
    val bar2: Bar = bar.nullableThing ?: return
    // do something with bar2
}
```

This works perfectly until you want to run something (like showing a message) before that "return" statement. I think it would look like this:

```kotlin
fun foo(bar: Bar) {
    val bar2: Bar = bar.nullableThing ?: run { 
        println("Error!")
        return
    }
    // do something with bar2
}
```

but that does not work (`'return' is not allowed here`).

**Edit:** My issue was actually with the continue statement, I did not know this would work with return. Here is a new piece of code that is more similar to the actual code:

```kotlin
data class Item(val str: String?)

val items = listOf<Item>(Item("tag:a"), Item("tag:b"), Item(null), Item("tag:c"))

val taggedItems = mapOf<String, String>("a" to "ItemA", "b" to "ItemB")

fun main() {
    for (item in items) {
        val stringItem = item.str?.let {
            if (it.startsWith("tag:")) taggedItems[it.substringAfter("tag:")]
            else it
        } ?: run {
            println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid")
            continue
        }
        compute(stringItem)
    }
}

fun compute(itemStr: String) = println(itemStr)
```

https://pl.kotl.in/SSU_z-Ctu
The error is  `'break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or a class boundary`.

Given this, I could create a function like this:

```kotlin
fun printError(item: Item): String? {
    println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid")
    return null
}
```

And then

```kotlin
... ?: printError(item) ?: continue
```

butt that would be awful

Comment: why not? It works fine with latest Kotlin https://pl.kotl.in/3OBwGHGGy

Comment: You can also tag an `also` onto the return value, if you like, e.g. `return true.also { println("wow") }` as a kind of side-effect, typically as a way to add a log statement without rewriting the line. Since this function returns `Unit` ("doesn't return anything") you'd have to do `return Unit.also { ... }`

Comment: Please provide the real code that gives you this error. As @AndreiTanana pointed out, your current code does work fine, so it is probably something else that prevents you from doing this.

Comment: your code should work fine ,if you created `run` yourself you have to make it inline to make return work as expected otherwise ypu have compiler error

Comment: I edited the code, and unfortunatly, `continue.also { println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid") }` does not work, the "also" block is unreachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just revert to traditional coding style:

```
fun main() {
    for (item in items) {
        val stringItem = item.str?.let {
            if (it.startsWith("tag:")) taggedItems[it.substringAfter("tag:")]
            else it
        }
        if (stringItem == null) {
            println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid")
            continue
        }
        // From here on, stringItem is smart-cast as non-nullable
        compute(stringItem)
    }
}
```

Though I would personally prefer avoiding anything that behaves similarly to a goto, such as `continue`:

```
fun main() {
    for (item in items) {
        val stringItem = item.str?.let {
            if (it.startsWith("tag:")) taggedItems[it.substringAfter("tag:")]
            else it
        }
        if (stringItem != null) {
            compute(stringItem)
        } else {
            println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid")
        }
    }
}
```

But if you really, really like to use scope functions as much as possible:

```
fun main() {
    for (item in items) {
        item.str?.let {
            if (it.startsWith("tag:")) taggedItems[it.substringAfter("tag:")]
            else it
        }.also {
            compute(it)
        } ?: println("Error: tag ${item.str} is invalid")
    }
}
```